# Separation of variables for heat equation with decay PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I've been trying to solve:

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
u_{t}-u_{x x}=-u,\,\, 0<x<L, t>0 \\
u_{x}(0, t)=1 \\
u(1, t)=0 \\
u(x, 0)=x^2 cos(\pi x) + 2x + 1
\end{array}\right.
$$

By separation of variables. My attempt:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&u(x,t)=F(t) G(x) \longrightarrow F^{\prime}(t) G(t)=F(t) G^{\prime \prime}(x)-F(t) G(x) \\
&F^{\prime}(t)=-\lambda^{2} F(t) \rightarrow \frac{F^{\prime}(t)}{F(t)}=\frac{G^{\prime \prime}(x)}{G(x)}-1=-\lambda^{2} \\
&G^{\prime \prime}-G=-\lambda^{2} G^{\prime}+\lambda^{2} F=0 \\
&F(t)=e^{-\lambda^{2} t}
\end{aligned}
$$

If $\lambda = \pm 1$
$$
G^{\prime \prime}=0 \longrightarrow G(x)=a x+b \\
\left.\begin{array}{rl}
\longrightarrow G(0) & =b=1 \\
\longrightarrow G^{\prime}(1) & =a+1=0
\end{array}\right\} \quad G(x)=1-x
$$

If $\lambda\neq \pm 1$
$$
G(x)=A \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1 x}\right)+B \operatorname{sen}\left(\sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1} x\right) \\
G^{\prime}(x)=-A \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1} \sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1} x\right) +B \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1} \cos \left(\sqrt{x^{2}-1} x\right)\\
\left.\begin{array}{rl}
\longrightarrow G(0) & =A=1 \\
\longrightarrow G^{\prime}(1) & =-\sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1} \sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1}\right)+B \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1} \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1}\right)=0 
\end{array}\right\} \\
G(x)= \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1 x}\right)+\operatorname{tan(\sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1})}\operatorname{sen}\left(\sqrt{\lambda^{2}-1} x\right) 
$$

From here, I don't know how to keep going. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only way you can use the separation of variables is when the boundary conditions are homogeneous. Your first step should be to introduce new variable $v(t,x)=u(t,x)+Ax+B$, such that for $v$ you have homogeneous conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Assuming

$$
G(x) = c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda^2-1}x)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda^2-1}x)
$$

From the conditions on $G'(0)$ and $G(1)$ we have to determine $c_1,c_2$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda ^2-1}\right) & \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda ^2-1}\right) \\
 \sqrt{\lambda ^2-1} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
c_1 \\
c_2
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

To avoid the trivial solution we choose $\lambda$ such that

$$
\det\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda ^2-1}\right) & \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda ^2-1}\right) \\
 \sqrt{\lambda ^2-1} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)=-\sqrt{\lambda ^2-1} \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda ^2-1}\right)=0
$$

or

$$
\lambda^2=\{1\}\cup\{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(2k-1)\right)^2+1,\ \ k\in \mathbb{N}\}
$$